# How many people can connect to ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm working with sockets. I'd like to know how many people can connect to my SocketServer using Sockets?

According to Cameron it is 2^16 different connection. So, as much as 2^16 people can actually use my chat at the same time(resources for handling so much users and other factors are not considered)???

https://www.quora.com/How-many-connections-can-a-JAVA-socket-server-hold

Comment: Cameron appears to have contributed quite a bit but there's nothing like a real test to prove what is true at the time of the test. It shouldn't take long to construct the test and execute it. As you add features to the application, you would add to your test suite and bless their outcome before you deploy.

Comment: Also a quick reminder that the `ServerSocket`'s maximum queue size is 50 incoming connections, and any past that are blocked. I think it's assumed you've already *accepted* the connections with this question, but I thought it might be nice to comment if you're expecting a large amount of users.

Comment: @jeff6times7 So, theoretically talking my simple server with just one ServerSocket can handle such an enormous quantity of users?

Comment: @Steve The ServerSocket really is not a concern to you. The resources and architecture you'll need to manage the 2^16 - 1 connections is.

Comment: @dewick47 Wait... So, at the same time no more than 50 users can send things to ServerSocket?

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I did not mean to confuse you. It can handle 50 *incoming connections*. I do not mean connections that have already been accepted by the `ServerSocket`. When you *accept* a connection through `.accept()`, the incoming connection is removed from the queue I'm talking about. In short, you can have 50 connections that *aren't accepted* yet before it will block others.

Comment: @dewick47 Everything is fine. ServerSocket can handle 2^16-1 users that were accepted through .accept() and 50 that wait to be connected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148624/discussion-between-steve-and-dewick47).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theoretical limit is 2^16 - 1.  Port zero is reserved.

The practical limit will be platform specific, and can only be determined by testing.

The limiting factors will include:

- available network throughput,
- the number of simultaneous connections that the OS kernel can sustain,
- the number of open file descriptors that a process is permitted, and
- the in-process resources required to sustain a large number of active connections.

Most of those are most likely to be hardware limitations.

---

The limit of 50 that people are talking above in comments is the number of connection requests that can be *queued*.  If your java application calls `ServerSocket.accept()` fast enough, requests won't be dropped.

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually working on chat app. Can you please tell me how many users may register in this chat? Is this number equals to 2^16-1? Or is it 50?

Comment: So, if 51 user will connect at the same moment the last one will not have a chance to be connected?

Comment: Probably, the connection packet will be dropped and the user's TCP stack will resend it after a period.  If the connect packets are repeatedly dropped, the user's client will see a connect timeout.  But if your Java server cannot keep up with the rate of new connections, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: Thank you. I think I begin to understand this. Also, every time I send a message I try to connect to ServerSocket, right? I use OutputStream for sending.

Comment: No.  Every time you call Socket.connect() you will be trying to connect to the ServerSocket.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac and Linux, you can do "ulimit", which will tell you the limit defined by the operating system.